# How to debug gigabit Ethernet on linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, ethernet

During testing network, I'm facing a very low throughput with gigabit Ethernet, which was implemented as RGMII mode, as follows:

```
$iperf - s
Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
0.0-10.0 sec   211 MBytes   176 Mbits/sec

$iperf - c <IP>
Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
0.0-10.0 sec   101 MBytes   83.6 Mbits/sec
```

I'm just a beginner with network on Linux then could anyone guide me some direction to debug and fix this issue?

The only thing I tried so far is that reading ethtool. There is nothing wrong observe here.

```
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 2
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)

        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Are you relying on iperf defaults - e.g. bandwidth defaulting on 1 Mbit/sec - or did you pass more specific options? Are you using TCP / UDP? What are the window / buffer sizes, and are they what you expect(ed)? If it's UDP, are you getting packet loss (expected / not)? The question, as it stands, is quite vague and an investigation can go in any direction...

Comment: Hi, I let iperf at default. I'm using TCP/IP. The buffer sizes I checked is 64. Actually, I expect bandwidth when setting it as client (iperf -c ...) equals to server (iperf -s). In my view, since it's gigabit ethernet so the bandwidth should be higher than 100Mbits/s.